# How to use Tweepy to retweet with a comment

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

So i am stuck trying to figure out how to retweet a tweet with a comment, this was added to twitter recently.

this is when you click retweet and add a comment to the retweet and retweet it.
basically this is what i am talking about :

[image]

i was looking at the api and count find a method dedicated to this. And even the retweet method does not have a parameter where i can pass text.

So i was wondering is there a way to do this?

Comment: Strange update_status is working for me. Did you try `api.update_status(stat_forme, tweet_cid)` because its throwing a syntax error using your code

Comment: `api.update_status(stat_forme, tweet_cid)` works
`api.update_status(stat_forme)` doesn't work... 403 bad request but if i add status like this it works  `api.update_status(status=stat_forme)`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tweepy doesn't have functionality to retweet with your own text, but what you can do is make a url like this **`https://twitter.com/<user_displayname>/status/<tweet_id>`** and include it with the text you want comment. It's not a retweet but you are embedding the tweet in your new tweet.

user_displayname - display name of person, whose tweet you are retweeting

tweet_id - tweet id of tweet you are retweeting

Comment: Update for those that wander in like me, Tweepy now (2020) has retweet functionality.  

http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.retweet

Comment: Just starting using tweepy but what it didn't exist (and still doesn't) is the functionality to retweet with a comment. From what they say in the question and answer, I think the plain retwwet already existed

Answer (score 4):

## September 2021 Update

Tweepy **does have the functionality** to quote retweet. Just provide the url of the tweet you want to quote into `attachment_url` of the `API.update_status` method.

Python example:

```py
# Get the tweet you want to quote
tweet_to_quote_url="https://twitter.com/andypiper/status/903615884664725505"

# Quote it in a new status
api.update_status("text", attachment_url=tweet_to_quote_url)

# Done!
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/client.html#tweepy.Client.create_tweet), there is a `quote_tweet_id` parameter in `create_tweet` method.

You can create a new tweet with the tweet ID of the tweet you want to quote.

```py
comment = "Yep!"
quote_tweet = 1592447141720780803

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token=access_token)
client.create_tweet(text=comment, quote_tweet_id=quote_tweet, user_auth=False)
```